# SwiftUI: TabView dynamic accentColor

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my app I have 2 tabs.

First tab view has white background.

Second tabView has black background.

Because of that I would like to change tabbar style depending on what TabBarItem selected

When tab1 is selected, I would like tab bar icons color to be:

```
 selected - black, unselected - grey
```

When tab2 is selected, I would like to change colors to:

```
selected - white, unselected - grey
```

I'm able to change icon color with `accentColor` property like that:

```
TabView {
    FirstTabView()
         .tabItem {
             Image("tab1").renderingMode(.template)
          }
    SecondTabView()
        .tabItem {
              Image("tab2").renderingMode(.template)
         }
 }.accentColor(.white)
```

But how to change icon color when user click on second tab ?

I tried something like that:

```
@State private var selection = 0

TabView(selection: $selection) {
        FirstTabView()
             .tabItem {
                 Image("tab1").renderingMode(.template)
              }
        SecondTabView()
            .tabItem {
                  Image("tab2").renderingMode(.template)
             }
     }.accentColor(selection == 0 ? .black : .white)
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update tab items `TabView` should be rebuilt, so try

Here is a full demo (colors changed for better visibility). Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("FirstTabView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle").renderingMode(.template)
                }.tag(0)
            Text("SecondTabView")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle").renderingMode(.template)
                }.tag(1)
        }
        .accentColor(selection == 0 ? .red : .blue)
        .id(selection)                        // << here !!

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work ((

Comment: Strange, try to change order of modifiers.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: It seems you did not set tags, so selection in your case was not really changed. See update with complete tested demo.